# ExtJS inheritance issue with multiple instances of an extending class

Tags: inheritance, extjs, extjs7

I have multiple forms that all start with the same, "universal" fields but then have different fields depending on the form. As such, I have a parent form that all the child forms are extended from. The parent form adds the universal fields so I don't have to re-declare those fields in the child forms.

The issue that I'm having is when I have multiple instances of the same child form, those univeral fields are re-added for each instance. Might sound a little confusing but I think the following fiddle should make it pretty clear: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/36lu&view/editor. Obviously I'm doing this incorrectly so just trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Code for the parent/child classes:

```
Ext.define('TestParentForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'testparentform',

    initComponent: function(){
        var me = this;

        if(!me.items){
            me.items = [];
        }

        Ext.Array.insert(me.items, 0, [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Universal Parent Field'
            }
        ]);

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});


Ext.define('TestChildForm', {
    extend: 'TestParentForm',
    xtype: 'testchildform',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Child-specific Field'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by defining items in the child class using the initComponent function. See fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/36nn&view/editor

```
Ext.define('TestParentForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'testparentform',

    initComponent: function(){
        var me = this;

        if(!me.items){
            me.items = [];
        }

        Ext.Array.insert(me.items, 0, [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Universal Parent Field'
            }
        ]);

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});


Ext.define('TestChildForm', {
    extend: 'TestParentForm',
    xtype: 'testchildform',

    initComponent: function(){
        var me = this;

        me.items = [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Child-specific Field'
        }];

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ext.Array.merge(arr0, arr1..) method.

```
Ext.define('TestParentForm', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'testparentform',
initComponent: function () {

    this.items = Ext.Array.merge(
        [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Universal Parent Field'
        }],
        this.items
    );

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/36lv&view/editor

Comment: And what's the point of merging it in the parent form, especially when `this.items` was never set before? If this would be one of the child forms, this rather would seem to work out.

Comment: I have added 3-rd child without any field and console.log-ed items property after callParent. Have a look at the fiddle again. As you can see the items property (Ext.util.ItemCollection) does not contain null or undefined value even when the this.items was not defined before. It means there is not need to check if items are defined before or not.
Your idea is also good, but I personally would prefer Ext.form.FieldSet or FieldContainer, and avoid to put sub-panel in panel.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it might not be [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)), but define a `Panel` with those default fields and then add it as the top-most item of the child forms; this can also be done with `xtype`. But honestly, for two simple text-fields, I wouldn't even mess around, for the sake of simplicity (nesting such tiny bits does not improve the readability). If it would be a few more items and a little more complex, nesting it might rather be a thing. Using inheritance in this case would make a whole lot more sense, if the main form had eg. custom validation methods, which the child forms also use - but as the fiddle shows, when it has UI components, it behaves just alike that when extending the class. Hint: ExtJS makes it easy to bind form to model, which may reduce the amount of code needed otherwise.